# Is there a way to determine resolution of a video using its bitrate?

Tags: video, resolution, video-encoding, bitrate

I have a use case where I need to determine the resolution of a video depending on its bit rate data e.g. 236k, 668k, 1299k, 1900k etc.

I also have data about its dimensions e.g. 320x240, 480x360 etc.

Is there a way of determining the resolution of the video using the bit rate and video dimension information ?

If yes then how ? If no then what is the information I require to calculate the resolution of the video ?

PS: I am new to the concept of resolutions, bit-rate etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video resolution, in its usual meaning, is *the same thing* as its dimensions in pixels, so the same 320px × 240px, or 1280×720 px (aka "720p"), &c.

It doesn't directly depend on bitrate; a lower bitrate *can* mean lower dimensions/resolution, but it can also mean a lower-quality video (more visible artifacts) at the same resolution, or it can mean a better video codec (more efficient compression) was used. So the only thing the bitrate *directly* tells you is how many bits (on average) were used for one second of the video.

(In some other contexts, such as images/photos, "resolution" might also mean DPI, but that's not relevant here.)